# How to map MySQL Timestamp field in Spring JAVA(JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am having trouble finding how to map different type of fields for different DBs in a Spring Boot Application. Primarily, I would like to know how to map the MySQL Timestamp but it would be great if I can also find a link to the collection of mappings for every datatype in different DBs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of standard basic types you can find [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic).

1. You can map `TIMESTAMP` to the following [Java 8 types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-datetime-java8):

`java.time.Instant`, `java.time.LocalDateTime`, `java.time.OffsetDateTime` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

2. You can also use outdated `java.util.Date` (see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-datetime)):

```java
@Column(name = "`timestamp`")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date timestamp;
```

But the first approach is much more preferable.

Comment: Java 8 provides new APIs for date time but why java.util.Date is outdated?

Comment: @AjayKumar Strictly speaking `java.util.Date` is not deprecated. But almost all its methods/constructors marked as such. And look also at [this article](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)